# Is there any way to connect to a remote computer except setting up psremoting in powershell

Tags: powershell

Can I remotely connect a computer/server without having to login into it not even once. I don't want to use one of these(enter-pssession/enable-psremoting/set-wsman) method. I have server's credentials and I want to restart a particular service from my local machine. Is there any other way out?
The server is behind firewall so i think it won't work using foreach loop.

I tried this, but it says RPC server not available

```
$mumbaiServers=Import-Csv "C:\Users\uname\Desktop\Learning&Development\mumbaiServers.csv"
$servers=$mumbaiServers.ServerName
$passwords=$mumbaiServers.Passwords

foreach($server in $servers) {

    foreach($password in $passwords) {

        $user="$server\myuser"
        $pass=echo "$password"
        Get-WmiObject win32_service -ComputerName $server -Credential $objCred
    }
}
```

Comment: Where's the `$objCred`? Anyway, if there's a firewall blocking RPC, it needs a rule that allows the connection. Without such a rule, remote access is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

Did you tried psexec? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psexec

Commandline looks like that to restart a service

```
psexec \\server -u username -p password net stop [service name] && net start [service name]
```

Comment: Ports 135 and 445 (TCP) need to be open

Answer (score 1):

Answer to your question-"I want to restart a particular service from my local machine. Is there any other way out?" is Yes.

Yes. If you only wanted to start\stop a service, you do not need to setup a persistence connection across the remote server(system). All you have to do is to use 'Invoke-Command' cmdlets and trigger your action.

For example-

> Invoke-Command -ComputerName XXX.XX.XX.XX -Credential stack\vibhor -ScriptBlock {ipconfig}

Here are the details for Invoke-Command-

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/invoke-command?view=powershell-6

Please note- even if they are behind the firewall you will have to enable atleast one channel to communicate through the required computers which can a port. The 'Invoke-Command' can connect through using that Port using -Port as an argument.

Comment: I cannot see the error here. Can you please paste the complete error here in comment?